# while sorting js object of arrays, it is returning keys array instead of objects

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```js
let originalFloorsArr = {
  '10': [1,2,3],
  '11':[1,2,3],
  '13': [1,2,3,4]
}

let reversedFloorsArr = {};
Object.entries(originalFloorsArr).map(([key, item], i) => {
  reversedFloorsArr[key] = Object.keys(item).sort(
    (a, b) => item[b] - item[a]
  );
});

console.log("originalFloorsArr", originalFloorsArr);
console.log("reversedFloorsArr", reversedFloorsArr);
```

In this example, instead of reutning `3,2,1` for index `10` it is returning `2,1,0`. However, there is no such value like 0 on `originalFloorsArr[10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you get the *keys* of the inner arrays, while you need the *values*. So replace

```
Object.keys(item).sort(
    (a, b) => item[b] - item[a]
);
```

with

```
Object.values(item).sort(
    (a, b) => b - a
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let originalFloorsArr = {
    '10': [1,2,3],
    '11':[1,2,3],
    '13': [1,2,3,4]
}

  
for(let key in originalFloorsArr) { 
   originalFloorsArr[key].reverse()
}

console.log(originalFloorsArr['10']) //returns [3,2,1]
```

To reverse each array value in each property, you can use the Object `for (let key in obj)` method to iterate through the object, then reverse the array using the array `reverse()` method.

Comment: This would only work if the elements in the arrays were in order.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. Using `.sort()` is the best solution then. Thank you Andy